# Как добавить элемент в объект JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, объекты

Есть вот такой массив, реализованный в виде объекта. Предназначен для динамической генерации css

```
var resultArray = {
      [resultInputSelector]: {
        'display': 'none'
      },
      [resultLabelSelector]: {
        'position': 'relative',
        'padding-left': '20px',
        'font-size': resultFontSize + 'px',
        'cursor': 'pointer'
      }
}
```

Необходимо добавить в массив значение - css свойство. Для этого пишу:

```
resultArray[resultLabelSelector].push({'border-radius': '50%'});
```

К сожалению не работает.

P.S. Все остальное работает. Не могу только добавить элементы в массив.

Comment: _Пробовал различные вариации со скобками - квадратными_ - стоило добавить попытки в вопрос. В данном случае не _массив, реализованный в виде объекта_ - а просто _объект_